# Create custom choice_label in symfony 5 EntityType

Tags: forms, symfony, entity, symfony5

I create a form and add EntityType field:

```
        ->add('name', EntityType::class, [
            'class' => MyTest::class,
            'choice_label' => function($name){
                return $name->getName();
            },
            'mapped' => false
        ])
```

I want show the Name that Category is car.

My database table is:

id | name | category

Answer (score 0):

Simply do this, in callback function on choice_label you are free to do anything to modify the label, in case category is a string skip the getName(), if you want to display the category not some string based on the category name skip the switch as well

```
->add('name', EntityType::class, [
            'class' => MyTest::class,
            'choice_label' => function(MyTest $entity){
                switch($entity->getCategory()->getName()) {
                    case 'car':
                        return 'It\'s a car!';
                }
                return $entity->getCategory()->getName();
            },
            'mapped' => false
        ])
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `query_builder` to your code.

```
    ->add('name', EntityType::class, [
        'class' => MyTest::class,
        'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er){
            return $er->createQueryBuilder('u')
                ->where('u.category = :category')
                ->setParameter('category', 'car');
        },
        'choice_label' => function($name){
            return $name->getName();
        },
        'mapped' => false
    ])
```